# Rails: Pg search, implementing dmetaphone with associated_against feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pg-search

after I created the :

```
rails g pg_search:migration:dmetaphone
```

I got this error:

```
Adding support functions for pg_search :dmetaphone
-- execute("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_search_dmetaphone(text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS $function$\n  SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT dmetaphone(unnest(regexp_split_to_array($1, E'\\\\s+')))), ' ')\n$function$;\n")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function dmetaphone(text) does not exist
LINE 2:   SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT dmetaphone(unnest(rege...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to install the `postgresql-contrib` package on your system.

Comment: Holy $code! I realized that was the problem on my Mac, here is how to fix it, maybe add it to your answer:
https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/wiki/Installing-Postgres-Contrib-Modules